# How to loop through a list in a template using SimpleTemplateEngine

Tags: templates, groovy

I would like to know if it is possible to loop through a list of values in SimpleTemplateEngine groovy. For example:

```
def values = [ "1", "2", "3" ]
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def text = '''\
    ???
'''
def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(values)
println template.toString()
```

How can I get:

```
1
2
3
```

by changing the variable `text`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean?

```
def values = [ "1", "2", "3" ]
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def text = '''
    ${values.each { println it} }
'''
println engine.createTemplate(text).make([values: values])
```

Comment: I think so. :-)

Comment: This print:

1
2
3

    [1, 2, 3] I don't want the array at end.

Comment: ${values.each { } } returns the array at the end.

Comment: I get the following error when using this code: `StreamingTemplateScript23.groovy: 1: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 1, column 308.` (newline)
   `or(_i, _s, e);}}.asWritable()}`

Answer (score 9):

```
def values = [ "1", "2", "3" ]
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def text = '''<% values.each { println it} %>'''
println engine.createTemplate(text).make([values: values])
```

Comment: this solution is working as expected, the above prints redundant array at the end [1,2,3]

Answer (score 5):

if you want an elegant template without many quotes and without a lot of imperative programming, you can do the following

```
def text = '''
<% for (item in values) { %>
<%= item %>    
<% } %>

'''
```

The rule is simple:

- Use `<%= ..%>` if there is rendering of value.
- Use `<% .. %>` if there is flow control handling ( if/else, for loop,... )

Comment: This has a downside of adding newlines between each item http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5101288475852800

Comment: you can remove those new lines it by `STRING.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*\\r?\\n|\\r?\\n\\s*(?!.*\\r?\\n)", "")`

Comment: There is an easier and more appropriate way: just add a backslash to the end of the line that you don't want to generate a newline. That is, `<% for (item in values) { %>\ ` would perfectly avoid unnecessary newlines in the loop.